# Spring tool suite 4.18.1.RELEASE maven pom auto suggetion not working

Tags: spring-tool-suite, m2eclipse

Open pom.xml with MAVEN POM EDITOR or xml editor,the auto suggesion/content assist not working.
Checked the following settings

1、xml editor content asssist
[image: Spring tool suite version]

2、Keys bind[image: keys bind]

[image: xml editor content assist]

Maven pom editor
[image: xml editor]
[image: pom editor]

Comment: The source editor part (when opening the pom file with the maven pom file editor) has been moved over to embed the generic editor, using some XML language server features behind the scenes, so the general XML preferences do not apply here, and content-assist might have changed quite a bit. Might be useful to post a screenshot of the pom editor that you have in use here to verify which exact XML editor component gets embedded here.

Comment: @MartinLippert see my new screenshot,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @martin-lippert,I figer out the solution,I disable all language servers,Checked with XML auto suggestion work.

[image: langauge server config]